# How load Angular 2 polyfils above Angular RC.1?

Tags: angular

Angular polyfills were located in `angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills` up to Angular RC0. But since RC it has been moved somewhere else. From where I can require it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is no more `angular2-polyfills.js` file. It's replaced by the following:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
```

You need to include explicitly ZoneJS and Reflect Metadata libraries. FYI angular2-polyfill contained these two libraries...

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. Some note: If you use a module bundler to load your vendors files, you can import them this way: `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js';`